# Restricting input to textbox: numbers only (can put negative sign, and only single decimal point)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to restrict input textbox, restriction of:

- only numbers
- only 1 period
- can put negative/minus sign on the beginning only

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you having an issue?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number -- Has links to polyfill and workarounds for non supporting browsers, of which there not many left.

Comment: Google Chrome is very good but Mozilla doesn't support the input type=number... @AshleyMedway

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="main"></input>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.onkeydown = codeFunc;

function codeFunc(e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var value = e.currentTarget.value;
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(code);
    codeFunc.isNegative = value.indexOf("-") > -1;
    codeFunc.isMiddle = value.length != 0;
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(code);
    if (letter == "-" && !codeFunc.isNegative && !codeFunc.isMiddle) {
        codeFunc.isMiddle = true;
        codeFunc.isNegative = true;
        return true;
    } else if (letter == "¾" && !codeFunc.isDecimal) {
        codeFunc.isMiddle = true;
        codeFunc.isDecimal = true;
        return true;
    }
    var test = /[\d\b]+/.test(letter);
    if (!codeFunc.isMiddle) {
        codeFunc.isMiddle = test;
        return codeFunc.isMiddle;
    }
    return test;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/HPhrn/1/)**

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR VERY FRIENDLY HELP!
I will try that.

Comment: Can only input numbers and 1 period, but cannot put 1 negative/minus sign in the beginning of input box.

Comment: @Momar you can't if you pressed `BACKSPACE`. you should handle that too. Try without pressing backspace.

Comment: @Momar Updated post with `Backspace` issue. you owe me a big party!! :D. Just kidding.

Comment: It still has drawbacks.. I used some code `3/4`.. use with complete responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to validate input on the keydown event of a text box:

**REGEX**

```
/^-?\d{2}(\.\d+)?$/
```

As a side note do some research into JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: I forgot how to use the regex. Please help me. How to use it?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1h3RQ51